# How to activate form field one by one with the valid values user entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I do have a Form and now I need to activate this form's field one by one. That mean If an user fill out first field correctly (Not empty and should be valid) then I need to activate second one and so on.

This is my HTML form:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Enter email" disabled>
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" disabled>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is how I tried it in `jquery`:

```
   function fakeValidator(event) {
     var $element = $(event.target);
        if ($element.val().length >= 3) {
            $element.addClass('valid');
        } else {
            $element.removeClass('valid');
        }
    }

    function enableNextElement(event) {
        var $element = $(event.target);
        if ($element.hasClass('valid')) {
            $element.closest('.form-group')
                .next('.form-group')
                .find('.sequence')
                .removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sequence').on('change blur keyup', fakeValidator);
        $('.sequence').on('change blur keyup', enableNextElement);
    });
```

This coding working for me but not work with validation. That mean if an user entered a not valid email next field is activating. But I want to keep next field disable till user entered a valid email.

Can anybody tell me how to do it?

**UPDATED HTML**

```
<form role="form" class="banner" method="post" action=""> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control first-name" autocomplete="off" required>
      <label for="name" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Enter Your Name"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control email-address sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled required>
      <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" rel="tooltip" title="Enter Your Email"></label>
      <span class="email-error"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number Eg: xx-xxx-xxx" class="form-control phone-number sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled required>
      <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" rel="tooltip" title="Enter Your Phone Number"></label>
    </div>
  </div>                   

  <div class="element-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
        <input type="text" name="charter-date" placeholder="Pick Up Date" class="form-control datepicker sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled>
        <label for="date" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" rel="tooltip" title="Prefered Charter Date"></label>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="element-right">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
        <input type="text" name="charter-time" placeholder="Pick Up Time" class="form-control timepicker sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled>
        <label for="time" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" rel="tooltip" title="Time of Charter"></label>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="element-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
        <input type="text" name="charter-date" placeholder="Drop Off Date" class="form-control datepicker sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled>
        <label for="date" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" rel="tooltip" title="Prefered Charter Date"></label>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <p class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">
      <span class="btn-orange-inner">Send</span>
    </button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your both function call simultaneously and you havent mention sequence class to textboxes so you can try

http://jsfiddle.net/Vishnuk/uqfe2403/6/

html

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control name sequence" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control email sequence" placeholder="Enter email" disabled>
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control phone sequence" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" disabled>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Script

```
function fakeValidator(event) {
     var $element = $(event.target);
        if ($element.val().length >= 3) {
            $element.addClass('valid');
            enableNextElement(event);
        } else {
            $element.removeClass('valid');
        }

    }

    function enableNextElement(event) {
        var $element = $(event.target);
        if ($element.hasClass('valid')) {
            $element.closest('.form-group')
                .next('.form-group')
                .find('.sequence')
                .removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sequence').on('change blur keyup', fakeValidator);           
    });
```

Comment: then not activating next field

Comment: @user3733831 you havent given .sequence class to textboxes

Comment: yes I have already check it with `.sequence` class. But no luck

Comment: please add .sequence class to your first testbox its working

Comment: Yes now it working. but check you DEMO, next field is activation if user entered a invalid email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92686/discussion-between-user3733831-and-vishnu-katpure).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(".form-control").focusout(function() {
  var t = $(this).val();
  var k = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (t) {
      k.parent().parent().next(".form-group").find(".form-control").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      k.parent().parent().nextAll(".form-group").children().find(".form-control").attr('disabled', '');
    }
  }, 0);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" class="banner" method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control first-name" autocomplete="off" required>
      <label for="name" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Enter Your Name"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control email-address sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled required>
      <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" rel="tooltip" title="Enter Your Email"></label>
      <span class="email-error"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number Eg: xx-xxx-xxx" class="form-control phone-number sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled required>
      <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" rel="tooltip" title="Enter Your Phone Number"></label>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group element-left">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="text" name="charter-date" placeholder="Pick Up Date" class="form-control datepicker sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled>
      <label for="date" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" rel="tooltip" title="Prefered Charter Date"></label>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group element-right">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="text" name="charter-time" placeholder="Pick Up Time" class="form-control timepicker sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled>
      <label for="time" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" rel="tooltip" title="Time of Charter"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group element-left">
    <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
      <input type="text" name="charter-date" placeholder="Drop Off Date" class="form-control datepicker sequence" autocomplete="off" disabled>
      <label for="date" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" rel="tooltip" title="Prefered Charter Date"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">
      <span class="btn-orange-inner">Send</span>
    </button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for nice solution. Just heard about `focusout`. But in my actual form it doesn't work. Because I added some HTML to my form. Can you tell me is it the problem? I updated answer with real html.

Comment: i have updated my code. that work fine with your updated html

Comment: But it has a problem. To activate next field user need to click out from the elements and then need to click again on the target element. isn't it?

Comment: you can also do this by using tab key.  the event was focusout

Comment: Yes it can be done using tab key. But it is not good for users. isn't it?

Comment: is there any other way to focus element except by clicking on it or focus using tab key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92690/discussion-between-user3733831-and-krupesh-kotecha).

Comment: in my code its working properly.  just add detail in to first field and then click on next field it will work.

Comment: But I need to use two clicks. one from out of elements and other one is on element